# Update Product Attribute through Import Tool using csv - ERROR: keep creating new same sku number - magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, import, import-products, less-import

I'm try to update a product attribute called "custom_stock_status". I have put together a csv file, with 2 columns like this, and import the file using import behavior "add/update", ***but it keeps creating the same sku number***, even-though the sku p1,p2,p3 are already exists in the backend.
**Everytime i try to import the csv file again, it create another SAME sku number in the backend.**

```
sku | custom_stock_status
p1    coming soon
p2    coming soon
p3    coming soon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working solution for magento 2.2.6

csv file look like

```
sku,attribute_name
ABC,[attribute_id]
```

script:

```
<?php $file = fopen('custom_status.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
// put inside the magento root, run it by command line "php -f UpdateCustomStatus.php" 

if ($file !== false) {

    //use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    /**
     * If your external file is in root folder
     */
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    /**
     * If your external file is NOT in root folder
     * Let's suppose, your file is inside a folder named 'xyz'
     *
     * And, let's suppose, your root directory path is
     * /var/www/html/magento2
     */
     //$rootDirectoryPath = '/public_html';
     //require $rootDirectoryPath . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

    // used for updating product info
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

    // used for updating product stock
    $stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    // add logging capability
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-update.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    // enter the number of data fields you require the product row inside the CSV file to contain
    $required_data_fields = 2;  //change for 3 to 2

    $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

    while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 350, ",") ) { //change to 350 at a time 

        $data_count = count($row);
        if ($data_count < 1) {
            continue;
        }

        $data = array();
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);

        $sku = $data['sku'];
        if ($data_count < $required_data_fields) {
            $logger->info("Skipping product sku " . $sku . ". Not enough data to import.");
            continue;
        }



        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////updating price/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try {
            $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $logger->info("Invalid product SKU: ".$sku);
            continue;
        }

        // You can set other product data with $product->setAttributeName() if you want to update more data
        //if ($product->getPrice() != $price) {
        //    $product->setPrice($price) 
        //            ->setStoreId(0) // this is needed because if you have multiple store views, each individual store view will get "Use default value" unchecked for multiple attributes - which causes issues.
        //            ->save();
        //}
        //if ($product->getPrice() != $price) {

        $status = trim($data['custom_stock_status']); //use corresponding attribute id in your csv file
        //$price = trim($data['price']);
        echo 'Getting product SKU: '.$sku.', with Custom Status: '.$product->getCustomStockStatus().'<br />\r\n'; 
        echo 'Updating product SKU: '.$sku.', with Custom Status: '.$status.'<br />\r\n'; // .' and Price:'.$price.'<br />';
        $product->setCustomStockStatus($status) 
        ->setStoreId(0) // this is needed because if you have multiple store views, each individual store view will get "Use default value" unchecked for multiple attributes - which causes issues.
        ->save();
        //}
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////updating quantity/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //try {
        //    $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
        //} 
        //catch (\Exception $e) {
        //    $logger->info("Invalid stock for product SKU: ".$sku);
        //    continue;
        //}

        //if ($stockItem->getQty() != $qty) {
        //    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
        //    if ($qty > 0) {
        //        $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
        //    }
        //    if ($qty < 1) {
        //      $stockItem->setIsInStock(0); //clean up first time
        //  }
        //    $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
        //}
    }
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```